# ChromeDriver will not run - Address already in use (98) - but nothing found to be using port 1915

Tags: linux, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, linux-mint

ChromeDriver will not run, saying that the current address is already in use. Whenever I have used lsof I have found nothing using port 1915, which is what ChromeDriver is wanting to use.

I've looked everywhere to find a solution for this but they all just say to kill whatever is using the port but I can't find any.
I also found a similar question on here at '[Chromedriver cannot be started due to address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044960/chromedriver-cannot-be-started-due-to-address-already-in-use)',
but that question shows their error is saying an IPv4 port is not available whilst mine says IPv6.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1553613641.983][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)
IPv6 port not available. Exiting...
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. This issue is critical for one of my projects which worked fine on windows, but I just recently moved to linux due to my windows getting corrupted and not wanting to have to deal with installing windows again, plus wanting a change-up in my day to day workings on the computer. Because of this, any tips given would be great if explained like I'm 5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you done `fuser -k 1915/tcp` to kill the port and then starting again?

Comment: Just tried it then, I get the same error. No change.

Comment: Note: Chromedriver uses 9515, not 1915.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, if this issue is because you have another chromedriver process in the background, you can just run `killall chromedriver`.

Answer (score 5):

```
fuser -k 9515/tcp
```

This one worked fine thanks for @Svilen

Comment: @Svilen Seems you missed an opportunity to make an answer.

Comment: @Jai this is what i'm getting: "Unknown option: k"

Comment: Kindly mention system config this will work fine in linux system.

Answer (score 5):

To identify the process id for ChromeDriver use `ps -fA | grep chromedriver`, Then kill the column two id number.

Comment: Use `sudo kill -9 <id>` with the process id you get from the first command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill chromedriver to get this working

```
   vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$ npx nightwatch --test ./tests/widgets/banner.test.js --testcase "Hide Row Label in Banner Widget" 
   Error: ChromeDriver process exited with code: 1
   [1663729485.869][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)

       at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
 [1663729485.869][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)



vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14354 pts/7    00:00:00 chromedriver
14416 pts/7    00:00:01 chrome <defunct>
14854 pts/7    00:00:00 npm exec serve
14878 pts/7    00:00:00 sh
14879 pts/7    00:00:00 node
15134 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
23260 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$ kill -9 14354
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$
```